# Validate depending properties in WPF and SL

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation, reactiveui

What is the recommended approach for validating two properties depending one on the other?

Classical example is *start* should be lower than *end* date:

1. user enters *start* "6th"
2. user enters *end* "3rd" - both fields should be marked as invalid
3. user corrects *start* to "1st" - both fields should be ok

How can ReactiveValidatedObject help here?

I preferably need a solution which works in WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: I know how to do this in Silverlight using the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface: if one of the related properties is changed - fire `ErrorsChanged` event for both properties. But I don't know how to do this in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM pattern for WPF app, it will be pretty straight forward. Instead of the View doing the validation, the ViewModel will do it. 
View should just be a dumb layer displaying whatever the ViewModel exposes. All UI validation should be done by ViewModel so that they are testable.

My ViewModel may look like this:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* declare ProperChanged event and implement  OnPropertyChanged() method */

    private DateTime _firstDate;
    public DateTime FirstDate
    {
        get { return _firstDate; }
        set
        {
            if (!AreDatesValid(value, _secondDate))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Incorrect First Date";
                return;
            }
            _firstDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstDate");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _secondDate;
    public DateTime SecondDate
    {
        get { return _secondDate; }
        set
        {
            if (!AreDatesValid(_firstDate, value))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Second Date";
                return;
            }
            _secondDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondDate");
        }
    }

    private string _errorMessage;
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set
        {
            _errorMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
        }
    }

    private bool AreDatesValid(DateTime firstDate, DateTime secondDate)
    {
        if(firstDate <= secondDate )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then databind View to this ViewModel ->

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MyViewModel}">
           <Grid>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SecondDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage}" />
           </Grid>
        <DataTemplate>
```